# Network Failure when using Response.TransmitFile

Tags: c#, .net, download, response

I'm trying to use below code, to allow the user to download an excel that is located on a local server:

```
FileInfo dest_file= new FileInfo(filename);
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "Excel/xls";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename = {0}", filename));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", dest_file.Length.toString());
Response.TransmitFile(filename);
Response.End();
```

However, after publishing the solution, downloading the file results in a Network failure. Any idea how I can solve this?

Note that the file downloads successfully when trying to access it through directory browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your using an invalid content-type

for **xlsx** use this

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

for **xls**

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
```